# Problems passing parameter to an action

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to pass data to an action inside the same controller. I'm using `RedirectToAction`, but I'm not succeeding.
The action is called but the data I'm trying to pass to it has its values ​​`null`.

My Model:

```
public class PlaylistModel
{
    public Guid PlayListID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Nome da Playlist")]
    public string NomePlayList { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Descrição")]
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Código")]
    public string CodigoPlayList { get; set; }
    public string Estado { get; set; }
    public string EmailUser { get; set; }
    public List<VideoThumbnails> VideosIdsYoutube { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Categorias")]
    public List<string> Categorias { get; set; }
}
```

This action receives the data, does the processing and calls the other action

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreatePlaylist(string Categorias, string NomePlayList)
{
    PlaylistModel playListModel = new PlaylistModel();
    playListModel.VideosIdsYoutube = AppCache.Instance.VideoParaAPI.VideoThumbnails.ToList();
    playListModel.Categorias = Categorias.Split(',').ToList();
    playListModel.NomePlayList = NomePlayList;
    playListModel.Estado = EnumEstadoDaPlayList.Nova.ToString();
    playListModel.EmailUser = AppUser.User.Email;

    var api = new AccessAPI.Playlist.AccessAPIPlaylist();
    var playlist = api.CriarNova(playListModel);

    if(playlist != null)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("ExibirPlaylist", new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Playlist", action = "ExibirPlaylist", pPlayList = playlist }));
    }
    else
    {
        return Problem("Não foi possível criar a playlist!");
    }
}
```

This other action is called by the previous one, but the model arrives with `null` values

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult ExibirPlaylist(PlaylistModel pPlayList)
{
    var apiVideo = new AccessAPI.Video.AccessAPIVideo();
    var videos = apiVideo.ConsultarPorPlayListId(pPlayList.PlayListID).ToList();
    if(videos.Count > 0)
    {
        videos.ForEach(v => 
        {
            pPlayList.VideosIdsYoutube.Add(new Dommain.Cache.VideoThumbnails() { CanalID = v.CanalID, DataDePublicacao = v.DataDePublicacao, NomeDoCanal = v.NomeDoCanal, NomeDoVideo = v.NomeDoVideo, Thumbnail = v.Thumbnail, VideoId = v.VideoIdYoutube});
        });
    }
    return View();
}
```

Comment: I've changed your `[asp.net-core]` tag to `[asp.net]` because your other tags (`[.net]` and `[asp.net-mvc]`) indicate that you're using ASP.NET (.NET Framework) rather than ASP.NET Core, so I assume this one was a mistake. If this isn't correct, please update your tags so that they all match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `RouteValueDictionary` in `RedirectToAction()` pass only simple types, like `string`, `int` etc. The `RedirectToAction()` doesn't serialize the complex data types. Therefore, may be the easiest way to use the `TempData`.

In the `CreatePlaylist(string Categorias, string NomePlayList)`:

```cs
TempData["playListModel"] = playlist;
return RedirectToAction("ExibirPlaylist");
```

And then:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult ExibirPlaylist()
{
    if (TempData["playListModel"] is PlaylistModel pPlayList)
    {
       // Your code using `pPlayList`
    }
    return View("Index");
}
```

***The MVC uses the binary serialization, by default. And in some cases the binary serialization can fail: [Storing objects (non-string things) in TempDataDictionary does not round trip correctly](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/2276). Therefore, it is preferably to serialize the specified object to a JSON string by [JsonConvert.SerializeObject()](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_SerializeObject.htm).***

Comment: I added the CreatePlayList action the following lines:                     
TempData["playListModel"] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(playlist);
return RedirectToAction("DisplayPlaylist");

In the DisplayPlaylist action, I did it as follows:                                                     
 PlaylistModel pPlayList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PlaylistModel>((string)TempData["playListModel"]);

passing pPlayList as a parameter to the view.

Comment: @Leonardo Silva: +1 Good point! I added an additional remark to the answer.